# How can I detect the changes in my SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql

I want to know the exact changes in my SQL Server database?
Can I see the complete changes in a SQL Database

Comment: See database transaction logs - they can be used for recovery, auditing and compliance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to know what data changed for the purpose of possibly synchronizing or validating the data later?
When we need to track data changes, we add a field to each table that we want to track and save the name of the field that was changed. 
Then we create an _AfterUpdate trigger that saves the field name that was changed.  If more then one field is changed in one row, we add a comma and the next feild name, etc.